# How to Make a Toggle Button that is Styled from a Checkbox that Changes the Color Theme Stay on the Same Color During Refreshes

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox that is styled as a toggle button. This checkbox is used to change the color theme. I want to find a way to make it not change the theme through refreshes.

```
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function switchTheme(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
}
else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
}
}

 toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

That was my javaScript that is to run this code.

```
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" title="change the theme color" id="checkbox">
        </label>
    </div>
```

That was my HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an id in the `<link>` tag placed in the `<head>` tag used to link the external css.

```
<head>
    <!--other tags -->
    <link id="page-theme" href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" title="" id="checkbox">
        <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
            change the theme color
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
```

and if you have a button, you can

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

checkbox.addEventListener("click", switchTheme);

// supose you have two stylesheet light.css and dark.css
function switchTheme(event) {
  const lightThemeSheet = "light.css";
  const darkThemeSheet = "dark.css";
  const isChecked = event.target.checked; //this return a boolean

  if(!isChecked) return

  // here you select the link tag in the head
  const pageThemeLink = document
    .getElementById("page-theme")
    .getAttribute("href");

  document
    .getElementById("page-theme")
    .setAttribute(
      "href",
      pageThemeLink === "light.css" ? darkThemeSheet : lightThemeSheet
    );
}
```

Comment: That I know, but I want to use a checkbox styled into a toggle switch instead of a button. But, thanks for trying.